# Gunicorn not reloading on form submit of flask app

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am  newbie to flask and gunicorn. I am using gunicorn for prod hosting. I have a submit button which stores the form data in database; i want the newly stored data to get picked from the database and be shown when the page is reloaded. What i observed is, Gunicorn does not reload any contents untill restarted. Can anyone please help me to reload the data without stopping the server?

- i have tried using --reload when starting gunicorn, didnt work. My application used to work as expected on flask's development server. So basically i want this functionality like in gunicorn: app.run(host=so.gethostbyname(so.gethostname()), port=v_port, debug=True, use_reloader=True). TIA

```py
############################ This is main_app.py #######################
from flask import Flask,  render_template, request, redirect, send_file, send_from_directory, current_app, flash, abort, jsonify, session, url_for
import os  as os
import sys as sys
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, NTLM
import ldap3
import socket   as so
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from subprocess import check_output
import ssl


v_port           = 2001

v_project_path   = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).replace('\\scripts','')
v_scripts_path   = v_project_path + os.sep + 'scripts' + os.sep  
sys.path.insert(0,v_scripts_path)

app = Flask(__name__)
import get_status as gs
#import save_cmnt as cmt
import base64
import struct
import cx_Oracle
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

SECRET_KEY = b"xyz"
class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = AES.block_size
        self.key = key

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * '0'

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:self.bs]
        raw_size = struct.unpack('<i', enc[self.bs:self.bs + 4])[0]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        raw_bytes = cipher.decrypt(enc[self.bs + 4:])
        print (raw_bytes)
        raw = raw_bytes[:raw_size].decode('utf_8')
        return raw

pass_f = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\python_db_pass.txt', "rb")
#pass_f = open(r'/apps/axiom_app/flask/python_db_pass.txt', "rb")

enc_db_pass=pass_f.read()
c = AESCipher(SECRET_KEY)
db_pass = c.decrypt(enc_db_pass)
ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect('axiom_data2/'+db_pass+'@RRANYT02') 
ora_cur = ora_con.cursor() 

def validate_credentials(connection):
    try:
        connection.bind()
        return True

    except Exception:
        pass
        return False
        
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        username = session['username']
        return 'Logged in as ' + username + '<br>' + "<b><a href = '/logout'>click here to log out</a></b>"
    return render_template("login.htm")


@app.route("/login", methods=[ "GET","POST"])
def login():    
    print('inside login')
    
    if (request.method == 'POST'): 
            print('in post')           
            username   = request.form['username']
            password   = request.form['password']
            print('login Name ' + username)
            
            server = Server(host='host',
                port=636,
                get_info=ldap3.ALL,
                use_ssl=True,
                allowed_referral_hosts='*',
                mode='IP_V6_PREFERRED')

            connection = Connection(server,
                                    auto_bind=False,
                                    receive_timeout=1000,
                                    client_strategy=ldap3.SYNC,
                                    raise_exceptions=True,
                                    version=3, user=r"intra\{0}".format(username),
                                    password=password,
                                    authentication=NTLM,
                                    check_names=True,
                                    read_only=True, auto_referrals=True)
            connection.start_tls()            
            User_return_value=validate_credentials(connection)
#            User_return_value = gs.user_login_auth(login_name)
            print('----- ',User_return_value)
            if User_return_value == False:
                return render_template("wrong_cred.htm")
            else :
                ##check if user has access
                ora_cur.execute("""select user_role from rs_user_access where username='"""+username+"""'""")
                user_role_details = ora_cur.fetchall()
                if len(user_role_details)==0:
                    return render_template("unauthorised.htm")
                else:
                    user_role=user_role_details[0][0] 
                    
                session['username']= username
                session.permanent = True
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            
            
    return render_template("login.htm") 

@app.route('/logout', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def logout():
   session.pop('username', None)
#   response = response()  
   return render_template("login.htm")

@app.route('/report_calender', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def report_calender():
   return render_template("dashboard.htm")

@app.route('/admin', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def admin():
   gs.get_admin_page(session['username'])
   if (request.method == 'POST') : 
       print('~~~~~~~~', 'adm post')
   else:
       print('~~~~~~~~', 'adm not post')
   admin_flag=request.form['admin_flag']
   print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~', admin_flag)
   if admin_flag=='0':
       return render_template("admin_page.htm")
   elif admin_flag=='1':
       user_name   = request.form['user_name']
       user_role   = request.form['user_role']
       
       gs.add_user_role(user_name,user_role)     
       gs.get_admin_page(session['username'])
       return render_template("admin_page.htm")
   elif admin_flag=='2':
       rm_user_name   = request.form['rm_user_name']
       gs.remove_user_role(rm_user_name)     
       gs.get_admin_page(session['username'])
       print('~~~~ removing', rm_user_name)
       return render_template("admin_page.htm")
   else:
       gs.get_admin_page(session['username'])
       return render_template("admin_page.htm")
          

@app.route("/dashboard", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def dashboard():
    if 'username' in session:
        if (request.method == 'POST') : 
            dashboard_flag   = request.form['dashboard_flag']
            if dashboard_flag=='0':
                print('normal refresh')
                gs.get_status(session['username'])
            else:
                print('in post')
                job_name   = request.form['job_name']
                email_flag   = request.form['email_flag']
            
                if email_flag=='1':
                    print('in email')
                    recipients = request.form['email_id']
                    email_content = request.form['email_content']
                    print(recipients)
                    email_file = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\templates\email.txt', "w")
                    email_file.write(email_content)
                    email_file.close()
        #            subprocess.call(['./send_email.sh'])
                    gs.get_status(session['username'])
                elif job_name:
                    print('in delay')
                    job_name   = request.form['job_name']
                    job_delay   = request.form['job_delay']
                    job_cmt   = request.form['job_cmt']
                    gs.submit_cmt(job_name,job_cmt,job_delay,session['username'])
                    gs.get_status(session['username'])
                else:
                    gs.get_status(session['username'])
        else:
            print('normal refresh')
            gs.get_status(session['username'])        
        
        return render_template("dashboard.htm")
    else:
        return render_template("wrong_cred.htm")

@app.after_request
def set_response_headers(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    return response
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(host=so.gethostbyname(so.gethostname()), port=v_port, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
    from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
    http_server = WSGIServer((so.gethostbyname(so.gethostname())))
    http_server.serve_forever()


############################ This is get_status.py ######################
import cx_Oracle
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
import pytz
#import sqlite3
import base64
import struct
#from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

SECRET_KEY = b"xyz"
class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = AES.block_size
        self.key = key

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * '0'

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:self.bs]
        raw_size = struct.unpack('<i', enc[self.bs:self.bs + 4])[0]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        raw_bytes = cipher.decrypt(enc[self.bs + 4:])
        print (raw_bytes)
        raw = raw_bytes[:raw_size].decode('utf_8')
        return raw

pass_f = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\python_db_pass.txt', "rb")
#pass_f = open(r'/apps/axiom_app/flask/python_db_pass.txt', "rb")

enc_db_pass=pass_f.read()
c = AESCipher(SECRET_KEY)
db_pass = c.decrypt(enc_db_pass)
ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect('axiom_data2/'+db_pass+'@RRANYT02') 
ora_cur = ora_con.cursor() 
ora_cur.execute("""select env from rs_env_details""")
env_details = ora_cur.fetchall()
env = (env_details[0][0])
    
def get_status(username):
    ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect('axiom_data2/'+db_pass+'@RRANYT02') 
    ora_cur = ora_con.cursor() 
    
    tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
    datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
    #print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    est_time= datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    est_date= datetime_NY.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    cur_time = datetime.strptime(est_date+" "+est_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
    cur_time = cur_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
    cur_time = datetime.strptime(cur_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
    print(cur_time)
    
#    c = AESCipher(SECRET_KEY)
#    db_pass = c.decrypt(enc_db_pass)
#    print(db_pass)
  
    ora_cur.execute("""select user_role from rs_user_access where username='"""+username+"""'""")
    user_role_details = ora_cur.fetchall()
    if len(user_role_details)==0:
        user_role='view'
    else:
        user_role=user_role_details[0][0] 
     
    print(user_role)
    
    ora_cur.execute("""select env from rs_env_details""")
    env_details = ora_cur.fetchall()
    env = (env_details[0][0])
    
#    ora_cur.execute("""select BD from  from axiom_job_da467762 where job_name='axm_c_rpt_tic_b_bl1_bd'""")
#    bd_details = ora_cur.fetchall()
#    bd = (bd_details[0][0])
                                     
    ora_cur.execute("""select t1.job_name,report_name,t1.report_type,report_sla,avg_run_time,avg_start_time,
                    status,start_time,end_time,delay_hrs,nvl(comments,'-') comments from rs_job_master t1
                    right join rs_job_status t2 on 
                    t1.job_name=t2.job_name
                    left join (select run_date,job_name,delay_hrs,comments 
                    from rs_job_delay where run_date='"""+est_date+"""' and id in (select max(id) from rs_job_delay group by JOB_NAME)) t3
                    on t1.job_name=t3.job_name
                    left join axiom_job_d1108822 t4 
                    on t1.job_name=t4.job_name where run_flag='Y' and t1.report_type!='MTY'
                    order by t1.report_type""")
                    
    
    html_s="""</br><div class="row" id="div_generate" >
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<text for="cob_date"> <b>Run Date</b> : """+datetime_NY.strftime("%d-%b-%y")+"""</text> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <text for="cob_date"> <b>ME BD </b>: """+'7'+""" </text> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <text for="est_time"> <b>EST Time</b> : """+(datetime.strftime(cur_time,'%d-%b-%y %H:%M'))+"""</text> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    
    <table  class="table1"><tr  class="row2"><th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="3%" width='90%'>Type</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="10%" >Report Name</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="7%">Status</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="10%">Start Time</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="10%">End Time</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="5%">Breach</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="5%">SLA</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="5%">ETA</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="3%">Delay (hrs)</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="20%">Comments</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="3%">&nbsp;</th></tr>"""
    
    email_content="""<table  class="table1">
    <tr  class="row2"><th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="3%" >Type</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="10%" >Report Name</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="7%">Status</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="10%">Start Time</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="10%">End Time</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="5%">Breach</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="5%">SLA</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="5%">ETA</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="3%">Delay (hrs)</th>
    <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff"width="20%">Comments</th></tr>"""
    
    rows = ora_cur.fetchall()
    
    if rows:
        table_data=""
        email_data=""
        for row in rows:    
            
            job_name=row[0]
            report_name=str(row[1])
            report_type=row[2]
            report_sla=row[3]
            avg_run_time=row[4]
            avg_start_time=row[5]
            status=row[6]
            start_time=row[7]
            end_time=row[8]
            delay_hrs=row[9]
            print("delay_hrs-",delay_hrs)
            comments=row[10]
            print("comments-",comments)
#            print(job_name)
#            print(end_time)
            
            sla_breach="-"
            eta='-'

#            print(start_time)
            ### ETA and SLA CALCULATION
            sla_time = est_date+' '+report_sla
            sla_time = datetime.strptime(sla_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
            sla_time = sla_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
            sla_time = datetime.strptime(sla_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
#            print(job_name)
            if status=='ACTIVATED' and delay_hrs is not None:
                print("here- ",delay_hrs)
                avg_start_time=est_date+" "+avg_start_time
                avg_start_time=datetime.strptime(avg_start_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                total_delay=delay_hrs+avg_run_time
                
                new_eta = avg_start_time + timedelta(hours=total_delay)
                new_eta=new_eta.strftime('%H:%M')
                eta = new_eta
                
                b_eta=est_date+' '+eta
                b_eta=datetime.strptime(b_eta,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                print(b_eta, sla_time)
                if sla_time<b_eta:
                    sla_breach='YES'
#                    print('Breaching')
                else:
                    sla_breach='NO'
#                    print('Not Breaching')
            
            elif status=='ACTIVATED' and delay_hrs is None:
                avg_start_time=est_date+" "+avg_start_time
                avg_start_time=datetime.strptime(avg_start_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                new_eta = avg_start_time + timedelta(hours=avg_run_time)
                new_eta=new_eta.strftime('%H:%M')
                eta = new_eta
#                print(report_name)
#                print(avg_start_time,sla_time,avg_start_time + timedelta(hours=avg_run_time))
                if (avg_start_time + timedelta(hours=avg_run_time))>sla_time:
                    sla_breach='YES'
#                    print('Breaching')
                else:
                    sla_breach='NO'
#                    print('Not Breaching')
            
            elif status=='SUCCESS':
                eta = 'NA'
                end_time=datetime.strptime(end_time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                end_time = end_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                end_time=datetime.strptime(end_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                
                start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                start_time = start_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                
#                start_time='Not Started'
#                print(end_time, sla_time)
                if end_time>sla_time:
                    sla_breach='YES'
#                    print('Breached')
                else:
                    sla_breach='NO'
#                    print('Not Breached')
                
            elif status=='RUNNING':
#                start_time=est_date+' '+start_time
                start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                start_time = start_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                
                new_eta=start_time + timedelta(hours=avg_run_time)
                new_eta = new_eta.strftime('%H:%M')
                                
                eta = new_eta
                
                if (start_time+ timedelta(hours=avg_run_time))>sla_time:
                    sla_breach='YES'
#                    print('Breaching')
                else:
                    sla_breach='NO'
#                    print('Not Breaching')
            else:
                if start_time != '-':
                    start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                    start_time = start_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                    start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                
                if end_time != '-':
                    end_time=datetime.strptime(end_time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                    end_time = end_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                    end_time=datetime.strptime(end_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                
                eta = '-'
                
            ### ETA and SLACALCULATION ENDS
            
            print("start_time:-",start_time)
            if start_time == '-':
                start_time='Not Started'
            else:
                start_time = start_time.strftime('%H:%M')
                start_time=str(start_time)
                
            if end_time == '-':
                end_time='-'
                print('1')
            else:
#                end_time=datetime.strptime(end_time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#                end_time = end_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
#                end_time=datetime.strptime(end_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
                end_time = end_time.strftime('%H:%M')
                end_time=str(end_time)
#                print('2')
            
            if delay_hrs == None:
                delay_hrs = '-'
            else:
                delay_hrs = str(delay_hrs)
#                print(start_time)
                
#            print(type(status))
            print(report_name,start_time,end_time,report_sla)
            table_data=table_data+"""<tr>
            <td>"""+report_type+"""</td>
            <td>"""+report_name+"""</td>
            <td>"""+status+"""</td>
            <td>"""+start_time+"""</td>
            <td>"""+end_time+"""</td>"""
            if sla_breach=='YES':
                table_data=table_data+"""<td bgcolor="red"><p style="color:FFFFFF">"""+sla_breach+"""</p></td>"""
            elif sla_breach=='NO':
                table_data=table_data+"""<td bgcolor="green"><p style="color:FFFFFF">"""+sla_breach+"""</p></td>"""
            else:
                table_data=table_data+"""<td>"""+sla_breach+"""</td>"""
            table_data=table_data+"""<td>"""+report_sla+"""</td>             
            <td>"""+eta+"""</td>
            <td><input type='text' height='3' style='border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box;' size="1" id='"""+job_name+"""_d' value='"""+delay_hrs+"""'></td>
            <td><textarea style='border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; ' rows='2' cols='50' name='"""+job_name+"""_c' id='"""+job_name+"""_c'>"""+comments+"""</textarea></td>"""          
            if user_role=='admin'  or user_role=='superuser':
                table_data=table_data+"""<td><button name='"""+job_name+"""_b' type='' value='' onclick="btn_sv('"""+job_name+"""')">Save</button></td>"""
            else:
                table_data=table_data+"""<td></td>"""
            table_data=table_data+"""</tr>"""
          
            email_data=email_data+"""
            <tr><td>"""+report_type+"""</td>
            <td>"""+report_name+"""</td>
            <td>"""+status+"""</td>
            <td>"""+start_time+"""</td>
            <td>"""+end_time+"""</td>
            """
            if sla_breach=='YES':
                email_data=email_data+"""<td bgcolor="red"><p style="color:black">"""+sla_breach+"""</p></td>"""
            elif sla_breach=='NO':
                email_data=email_data+"""<td bgcolor="green"><p style="color:black">"""+sla_breach+"""</p></td>"""
            else:
                email_data=email_data+"""<td>"""+sla_breach+"""</td>"""
            email_data=email_data+"""<td>"""+report_sla+"""</td>             
            <td>"""+eta+"""</td>
            <td>"""+delay_hrs+"""</td>
            <td>"""+comments+"""</td></tr>
            """
    email_e="""</table>
    <p>
            For further queries, please contact <a href="mailto:saket.parab@barclays.com">Saket Parab.</a>
        <p>
            Regards,
            <br>
            <b>Axiom Dev</b>
        </p>
        </body></html>"""
    
    e = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\templates\email_1.txt', "r")
#    e = open(r'/apps/axiom_app/flask/templates/email_1.txt', "r")
    email_head=e.read()
    email_data=email_data+email_e
    email_content=email_head+email_content+email_data
    email_content=email_content.replace('{DATE_HERE}',datetime_NY.strftime("%d-%b-%y"))
    email_content=email_content.replace('{TIME_HERE}',est_time)
#    print(email_content)
     
    html_e="""</table>
    </br>"""
    if user_role=='admin' or user_role=='superuser':
        html_e=html_e+"""
    <form id='cmt_form' method='POST' action = '/dashboard' enctype='multipart/form-data'>    
      <input class='add_input' type='hidden' name='job_name' id='job_name' placeholder=''>
      <input class='add_input' type='hidden' name='job_delay' id='job_delay' placeholder=''>
      <input class='add_input' type='hidden' name='job_cmt' id='job_cmt' placeholder=''>
      <input class="add_input" type="hidden" name="dashboard_flag" id="dashboard_flag" >
     
      <textarea name='email_content' style="display:none" id='email_content' >"""+email_content+"""</textarea>
      <input class='add_input' type='hidden' name='email_flag' id='email_flag' placeholder=''>
      <input class='add_input' type='' name='email_id' id='email_id' placeholder=''>
      <button name='email_b' type='' value='' onclick='btn_em()'>Email</button>
    </form>"""
    
    html_e=html_e+"""</div></body></html>"""
#    print(table_data)
    final_html=html_s+table_data+html_e
    
    f = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\templates\dashboard_1.htm', "r")
#    f = open(r'/apps/axiom_app/flask/templates/dashboard_1.htm', "r")
    html_head=f.read()
    html_head=html_head.replace('{ENV_HERE}','('+env+')')
    html_head=html_head.replace('{USERNAME_HERE}',username)
    #print(f.read())
    
    html_file = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\templates\dashboard.htm', "w")
#    html_file = open(r'/apps/axiom_app/flask/templates/dashboard.htm', "w")
    html_file.write(html_head+' '+final_html)
    html_file.close()
    print('done')
    ora_cur.close()
    return 'refresh'
    
def submit_cmt(job_name,job_cmt,job_delay,username):
    tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
    datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
    #print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    est_time= datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    est_date= datetime_NY.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    cur_time = datetime.strptime(est_date+" "+est_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
    cur_time = cur_time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
    cur_time = datetime.strptime(cur_time,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
    
    ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect('axiom_data2/'+db_pass+'@RRANYT02') 
    ora_cur = ora_con.cursor() 
    ora_cur.execute("insert into rs_job_delay values((select nvl(max(id),0)+1 from rs_job_delay),'"+est_date+"','"+job_name+"',"+job_delay+",'"+job_cmt+"','"+username+"')")
    ora_cur.execute('commit')
    ora_cur.close()
    return 'cmt saved'

def user_login_auth(user_window_id):
    ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect('axiom_data2/'+db_pass+'@RRANYT02') 
    ora_cur = ora_con.cursor() 
      
    logged_in_user = user_window_id
    v_sql="select count(1) as cnt from DS_REPORT_S1060297 where user_windows_id ='"+logged_in_user+"' and user_active='Y' "
    
#    print(v_sql)    
    ora_cur.execute(v_sql)
    rows = ora_cur.fetchall()
    
    res_list=[i[0] for i in rows]
        
    if (res_list == [1]) :        
        return 0
    else:        
        return 1

def get_admin_page(username):
    login_user_role=''  
    ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect('axiom_data2/'+db_pass+'@RRANYT02') 
    ora_cur = ora_con.cursor() 
    ora_cur.execute("""select user_role from rs_user_access where username='"""+username+"""'""")
    user_role_details = ora_cur.fetchall()
    if len(user_role_details)==0:
        login_user_role='view'
    else:
        login_user_role=user_role_details[0][0] 
    
    f = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\templates\dashboard_1.htm', "r")
#    f = open(r'/apps/axiom_app/flask/templates/dashboard_1.htm', "r")
    html_head=f.read()
    html_file = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\templates\admin_page.htm', "w")
    html_body='</br><center><div style="max-width: 98%;">'
    if login_user_role=='superuser' or login_user_role=='admin':
        html_body = html_body+'''<label for="fname">Windows User Name </label>
                      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
                      <select name="userrole" id="userrole">
                      <option value="superuser">Superuser</option>
                      <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                      <option value="view">View</option>
                      </select>
                      <button name='add_role' type='' value='' onclick="btn_add_role('add_role')">Add User</button>
                      </br>'''
    
    html_body = html_body+'''</br><table  class="table1"><tr  class="row2"><th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="">User Name</th>
                <th align="left" bgcolor="b3d9ff" width="10%" >User Role</th>
                <th align="left" width="10%" >&nbsp;</th></tr>'''
    ora_cur.execute('select username,user_role from rs_user_access')
    rows = ora_cur.fetchall()
    
    if rows:
        for row in rows:                
            user_name=row[0]
            user_role=row[1]
            html_body=html_body+'''<tr><td>'''+user_name+'''</td> <td>'''+user_role+'''</td>'''
            if login_user_role=='superuser' or login_user_role=='admin': 
                if user_role=='superuser':
                    html_body=html_body+'''<td>&nbsp;</td>'''
                else:
                    html_body=html_body+'''<td><button name="'''+user_name+'''_b" onclick='btn_remove_role("'''+user_name+'''")'>Remove</button></td></tr>'''
            else:
                html_body=html_body+'''<td>&nbsp;</td>'''
                
        html_body=html_body+'</table>'
        html_file.write(html_head+' '+html_body+' </div></center></div></body></html>')
        
        html_file.close()
    
    print(user_role)

def add_user_role(user_name,user_role):    
#    print("insert into rs_user_access values('"+user_name+"','"+user_role+"')")
    ora_cur.execute("insert into rs_user_access values('"+user_name+"','"+user_role+"')")
    ora_cur.execute('commit')
    
    
def remove_user_role(user_name):    
    ora_cur.execute("delete from rs_user_access where username='"+user_name+"'")
    ora_cur.execute('commit')
    
get_status('')
```

Comment: I've you've built the application properly, anything coming from the database *should* update when the page is reloaded, without the need to activate the live reloader which is designed for reloading python source code files which have changed during development.  Some code samples of how you're getting this data from the database are needed for anyone to help solve this.

Comment: thanks for your reply v25. I have added the code snippet

Comment: Can you show more surrounding code.  It's not clear if this is within a Flask view function, or at the global level, which could effect why these changes only appear with the live reloader active.

Comment: V25, i am creating content of the html tables on the fly from the python code. is this the reason? i have attached the snippet above. can you send me an example how i should paint database data on the webpage using flas?

Comment: Can you gist or pastebin the entire file?  By surrounding code, I wanted to see the function definitions and any `@app.route` decorators, down to the last `return` statement.

Comment: Hi, i dont know how to gist, i have pasted the two main files of my app. Please let me know if this helps. * i am running the app in windows and unix. i am facing the gunicorn issue in unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it needs re-designed.  I'll try to explain the issue...

You're writing to template files at various points throughout the code.

For example in the `get_status` function you do:

```
html_file = open(r'C:\unix_report_status\templates\dashboard.htm', "w")
```

Then you write some HTML to that file.

However you then call this function at various points in your Flask view functions:

```
@app.route("/dashboard", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def dashboard():
    # ...
    # some if statements ...
                gs.get_status(session['username'])
```

Then proceed to return the rendered template which was written when the `gs.get_status` function was called:

```
        return render_template("dashboard.htm")
```

The problem with this, which might not be immediately apparent, is that **as soon as multiple requests from different users start hitting this app, they are going to fight to overwrite the template files, resulting in random errors.  This application won't scale to multiple users at-all.**

I think you need to go back and re-design this, so that you're not manually writing to the template files all the time.  Read about [Flask Templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/) which support [Jinja Syntax](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/) and use this to achieve what you're trying to do manually.

This will let you have a template file on disk which never changes, and can contain Jinja Syntax like:

**dashboard.html**

```
<p>Show me {{ some_variable }}.</p>
```

And some corresponding code to populate that, passing arguments to `render_template`:

```
def get_status():
    # Any old logic
    return 'success'

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    result = get_status()
    return render_template('dashboard.html', some_variable = result)
```

Which renders as:

```
<p>Show me success.</p>
```

With this approach you automatically support many requests as the templates are rendered on demand with dynamic data.

Perhaps this wasn't the answer you wanted, but it's probably best to re-design this app to use the Jinja2 templating engine, and cure the database reload bug in the proccess.  Finding a workaround like the `--reload` flag to make gunicorn behave like the development server will probably lead to further unforseen problems down the line.

Comment: Hi V25, i get what you are trying to explain. Its better to go through the pain of redesigning the app than regretting later. Thanks a lot for such a wonderful explanation.